# Select records that do not have a related record with condition in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have two models Room and Booking.

The models are as follows:

```
class Room extends Model {
 public function bookings() {
  return $this->hasMany(Booking::class);
 }
}

class Booking extends Model {
 public function room() {
  return $this->belongsTo(Room::class);
 }
}
```

I want to use laravel's eloquent to select all Rooms that do not have a booking at a given date, say, 2018-06-07.

I have tried the following:

```
$available_rooms = Room::whereHas('bookings', function($query) {
 $query->where('date', '!=', '2018-06-07');
})->get();
```

However, this only returns the rooms that have any bookings and not those that do not have any at all.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `doesntHave()`

```
$available_rooms = Room::doesnthave('bookings','or' ,function($query) {
 $query->where('date', '!=', '2018-06-07');
})->get();
```

It will return the rooms that are not booked for this day.

for more information, you can https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_doesntHave

Hope this helps.

Comment: this throws me "Object of class Closure could not be converted to string" when I do "->get()"

Comment: This seems to return only those rooms that do not have bookings at all rahter than the ones who only do not have a booking for that date.

Comment: Try this $available_rooms = Room::doesnthave('bookings','or' ,function($query) {
 $query->where('date', '!=', '2018-06-07')->get();
});

Comment: Still returns only the rooms that do not have any bookings at all.

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer? I believe the condition is reversed, it should be `$query->where('date', '==', '2018-06-07');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [doesntHave](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L910)

```
$available_rooms = Room::doesntHave('bookings', function($query) {
    $query->where('date', '!=', '2018-06-07');
})->get();
```

Comment: this throws me "Object of class Closure could not be converted to string" when I do "->get()"

Comment: `doesntHave()` is such a strange choice of name. Nowhere else is "not" abbreviated to "not". `doesNotHave` would have been a much better choice. Sorry, nothing to contribute - just an observation of a whacky name.